# Counting punctuation marks in a text file using ArrayList and loops arent working properly, how to fix?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

SOLVED.

I am trying to count how many punctuation marks there are in a text file. I'm using if statements to count the number of each punctuation mark and doesn't seem to be working, it says every element is a full stop.

this is my loop

```
    for (int c = 0; c <= punk1.size()-1; c++) {
        if (punk1.get(c).matches(".")) {
            fullstop += 1;
        } else if (punk1.get(c).matches(",")) {
            comma += 1;
        } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("?")) {
            qmark += 1;
        } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("!")) {
            expoint += 1;
        } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("\"")) {
            doublequote += 1;
        } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("\'")){
            singlequote += 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Punctuation Marks not Found");
        }
    }
```

and this is the output.

```
Punctuation marks in text file: [., ., ., ,, ,, ,, !, !, !, ?, ?, ?, ", ",", ', ', ']
Number of Punctuation marks in file: 18
Number of fullstops: 18
Number of commass: 0 
Number of question marks: 0 
Number of exclamation point: 0 
Number of double quotes: 0 
Number of singlequotes: 0
```

there should be 3 for each.

Comment: did you try with `equals()` instead of `matches()`?

Comment: I did not. Thank you, I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use matches keyword with the regex expression, you should be careful with the regex expression.

You have to escape `.` `?` `"` and `'` with backslash.

Try the following code:

```
for (int c = 0; c <= punk1.size()-1; c++) {
    if (punk1.get(c).matches("\\.")) {
        fullstop += 1;
    } else if (punk1.get(c).matches(",")) {
        comma += 1;
    } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("\\?")) {
        qmark += 1;
    } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("!")) {
        expoint += 1;
    } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("\"")) {
        doublequote += 1;
    } else if (punk1.get(c).matches("\'")){
        singlequote += 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Punctuation Marks not Found");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, You can also use `equals` for comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed it to equals, but thank you for showing how to do it with .matches. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `matches` which uses a regex match. Since '.' matches any character the first if condition is always true.

Comment: should I use something different to matches? or are they okay for the others just not for the '.' ? and how can i make it check for just '.'?

Comment: If your punk1 contains Strings of single characters, use `equals` instead of `matches` and that should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I am using equals() now. I'm glad it was a simple problem to fix. I should have really thought of it myself. I used matches because i was using regex earlier in the code, and i don't fully understand it yet.

Answer (score 3):

The `.matches` method takes a regular expression as parameter. The *problem*, in your case, is that the period character is a special character in regular expression syntax, which means *match any character*, thus, your first `if` statement will always hold true.

To fix this, you can simply replace `punk1.get(c).matches(".")` with `punk1.get(c).matches("\\.")`. This will *escape* the period character so that it will be matched *literally*.

Alternatively, you can use the `contains` method which will take the strings as they are.

Comment: I tried the \\. and i think it worked but then the program failed at the ?, I will use the equals() to match them, which is think is the exact same as contains.

Comment: @Mr_Fishy52: The `?` is also a special character in regular expression syntax, and the solution would be the same. I would recommend you replace the `matches` with `contains`. The `equals` will attempt to match the entire string, so even if the string will contain what you are after, the result would be false if the string values do not match.

Comment: the arraylist punk1, has already been added with only punctuation marks in each element, using the regex //p{Punct}, so would equals be okay to use in this instance, where the element will either be . or ? or something or it wont be?

Comment: @Mr_Fishy52: If I am following, `//p{Punct}` should yield true if the string contains at least 1 punctuation mark. The `equals` will check to see that both strings are equal, thus, `"abc.".equals(".")` will yield false. The `.contains` will check to see that the string you are passing is present.